# codeigniter sending a variable from ajax to controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm currently doing an ajax add,update and delete. And I think I'll just start with the delete since it is the easiest and hope that it might help me in the others.

In jquery (this is inside $doc.ready and the event is triggered properly)

```
if ($a == "Delete") 
{
    var postid = $(this).next('.postid').val();
    $(this).closest(".todo-content").fadeOut();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "<?=base_url()?>.index.php/classes/deletepost",
        data: {postid: postid},         
        async: false,
  });
}
```

in html

```
<form method="post">
    <button class="btn" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this item?')">Delete</button>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="postid">
</form>
```

In controller

```
public function deletepost(){
        $id = $this->input->post('postid');
        $data = array('active' => 0);
        $this->Model_name->deletepost($id,$data);
        redirect('/abc/123');
    }
```

This is already working but then I am planning on making the crud to ajax. I'm trying to pass the `postid` from ajax to controller to delete this post. The `fadeout` already works but only the ajax does not. I'm very new to ajax so I do not know where I am going wrong and I might also ask questions again regarding the other parts of crud.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

The problem was the url inside the `$.ajax`. It returns a garbage.

So I added a script in the header

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var BASE_URL = "<?php echo base_url();?>";
</script>
```

And just use `BASE_URL` in the `url:` like so `url: BASE_URL+'classes/deletepost',`

Answer (score 0):

Please Try to follow this:

**In Codeigniters View:**

```
<!-- Store ID and baseurl as attributes . this would help you to fetch data -->
    <button class="btn" postId="5" baseUrl="<?php echo base_url();?>" id="button">Delete</button>


    <!-- Store ID and baseurl as attributes . this would help you to fetch data -->
    <button class="btn" postId="5" baseUrl="<?php echo base_url();?>" id="button">Delete</button>
    <!-- reading jquery file .. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jquery/js_search/jquery.js"></script>
    <!--you can write file in extra js file .. it depends on you -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#button').click(function(){
    // ask for confirmation
    var result = confirm("Want to delete?");

    // if it is confirmed
    if (result) {
    // get baseURL and ID using attributes
    var base_url = $('#button').attr('baseUrl');
    var postid  = $('#button').attr('postId');

    // make a ajax request
    $.ajax({
    url: base_url,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        if(data){
                // Fade out the content id
                $('#content_id').closest(".todo-content").fadeOut();

        }       
    }
    });



    }

    });

    </script>
```

in controller:

```
// You just need to delete the post and return a status code of "200"
public function deletepost(){
        $id = $this->input->post('postid');
        $data = array('active' => 0);
        $this->Model_name->deletepost($id,$data);
        redirect('/abc/123');
    }
```

Comment: I've already fixed it. The problem was the `url` inside the ajax. It returns some garbage. Declaring base_url in the header seems to be easier.

Comment: ow .. great! all the best! :)